# nuget install creating subfolders

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I'm running the following nuget command to extract a dll from a nuget package located in C:\utils and extract it to C:\dll.

```
nuget.exe install -o C:\dll TDS.AppLogger -source C:\utils
```

The dll gets extracted to C:\dll\TDS.AppLogger.1.0.0\lib\net452.  I'm not sure why it's creating the TDS.AppLogger.1.0.0\lib\net452 subfolders.

Is there an option in the command that I can include which would not create the subfolders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Leo-MSFT - Thanks for your response.

I ended up using MSBuild and adding the Unzip task to unzip the nuget package and extract it's contents to a destination location.

```
 <Unzip ZipFileName="$(ReleasePath)\exe\utils\AppLogger.1.0.0.nupkg" TargetDirectory="$(ReleasePath)\exe\dll\" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an option in the command that I can include which would not create the subfolders?

I am afraid not. That because this command is not used to extract a dll from a nuget package, but extract NuGet package from `.nupkg` files. See [Install command for NuGet CLI reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#install), this command **similar to restore in that it only adds packages to disk in a hierarchical layout**. And you can check the command about [NuGet CLI reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#add), there is no option in the command to extract a dll from a nuget package.

To resolve this issue, you can consider use a .bat file to extract a dll, below is a sample code:

```
@echo off


echo Extracting all dlls from nugets to folder C:\dll

REM %mypath% is where the batch file is located
set mypath=%~dp0

set temppath=%~dp0temp\
set dllpath=C:\dll\


mkdir %dllpath%

rem traverse all nupkg files
pushd %mypath%
    for /r %%a in (*.nupkg) do (

        echo \- Processing %%~nxa

        REM unzip nuget to %temppath% folder.
        powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command "& { Add-Type -A 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'; [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('%%a', '%temppath%'); }

        REM Copy all dlls 

        pushd %temppath%
            for /r %%b in (*.dll) do (
                echo     \- Found %%~nxb
                COPY "%%b" "%dllpath%%%~nxb"
            )
        popd

        REM Delete Temp folder
        rd /s /q %temppath%"
    )
popd

pause
```

The source code from [here](https://gist.github.com/fex80/976ff887acb825171de6).

Just put the bat file under the folder: `C:\utils`