# Using Unzip task in MSBuild to extract binaries

Tags: c#, regex, msbuild, unzip, msbuild-task

I am using the unzip msbuild task to extract files from a nuget package.  Some of the DLLs have a space in between the names (i.e., "Product Name.dll").  After the files are extracted, the space is replaced with a "%20."

Is there a property that I can set in the Unzip MSBuild task to prevent the spaces turn into the ascii "%20"?

Otherwise, I can think of two options:

1) Looping thru the files in the directory finding which ones had the "%20" and rename those files instead with a space. I know there is a copy task in msbuild, but I wasn't sure how to loop thru the files.

2) Doing a string replace on the files that have "%20" in the name and replacing that with a space.  How do I retrieve the file names though?

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I found the FileUpdate task and tried using it with the following code:

```
<ItemGroup>
 <SourceFiles Include="C:\test\lib\AQS\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="RenameFiles">
 <FileUpdate Files="@(SourceFiles)" Regex="%20" ReplacementText=" " />
</Target>
```

However, it doesn't replace the text "%20" with a space.  I'm pretty sure that's because I haven't used the Regex property correctly.

Can someone please explain what the Regex should equal?

Comment: can you try to escape the `%` again? => `%2520`

Comment: Didn't work.  I replaced the Regex from "%20" to "%2520" and it didn't replace the "%20" in the file name to a space.

Answer (score 0):

No no no. Do not reinvent the wheel by unzipping nuget packages yourself. Nuget.exe from the command line already does that for you, and it does it correctly too! Look up Nuget restore:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#command-line-restore

Restore will pull down the packages, put them in the right place, unzip them etc...

Then your real task should be to do nothing with them. MSBuild will automatically (Or should) then copy them with your assembly to your build output folder.

Comment: I tried the nuget.exe install and it was creating subfolders when extracting the dll files.  See here for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46814805/nuget-install-creating-subfolders/46822151#46822151

Comment: Of course it creates subfolders. But nuget itself will hook up the path for you. You don't have to do write paths to them yourself. Nuget files are supposed to just work. You add a dependency and then forget about it.